# Web API Best Practice for Deep Object Routes

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

When designing a RESTful API with ASP.NET Web API, I can create several routes to retrieve the same data. But should I? Is it considered helpful or confusing?

For example, if I have an object relationship of Parent > Child > Item, I could potentially have three routes return the same individual item:

- api/parents/:parent/children/:child/items/:item
- api/children/:child/items/:item
- api/items/:item

Is it useful to provide all three routes, or should it be limited to the simplest route to avoid confusion? Is there a best practice in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing which URIs/routes to use is a matter of the desired purpose, not content. Is it possible or propable that a user would look for a child without having a specific parent in mind? If yes, offer the data in a  seperate root URI, if not, restrict access to the child data by requiring the user to provide a parentId.

The URI `api/children` would return all children regardless of their parents and therefore fulfills another purpose than `api/parents/:parentId/children` which would only return the children the :parentId instance actually has a reference to. The result will always contain data that can also be obtained using `api/children`, but it carries additional information because these children 'belong' to the specified parent.

In my opinion all of your options are valid because they all have different purposes. However I would avoid using different URIs for the same purpose.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has access to the lowest-level unique identifier (:item in your case), then they should just call

api/items/:item

the information about the parent would be redundant / irrelevant.

i would go:

```
api/parents
api/parents/:parentid
api/parents/:parentid/children
api/children
api/children/:childid
api/children/:childid/items
api/items
api/items/:itemid
```